# Update ruby gem version with new changings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemspecs

I have developed a gem for learning purposes and push it to https://rubygems.org/gems/combination-pairs. Now I want to do some changes in the code of the gem. Means I want to update my same gem but with different version. How can we do the same??

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to update your ruby gem with changes:

1. Keep testing your code and make the required changes in your gem code (locally)
2. Once you are done with Step 1, update the version of your gem in `lib/combination/pairs/ version.rb` file by following the [Semantic Versioning Guidelines](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#semantic-versioning). Let's say you change the version of your gem to `0.0.2`
3. Next, run `bundle install` command in your gem's working directory to install all the gem dependencies.
4. And finally, run the task `rake release` which will create tag `v0.1.2` and build and push `combination-pairs-0.0.2.gem` to Rubygems. This task is available to you as I see that you have the following line in the `Rakefile`

   ```
   require "bundler/gem_tasks"
   ```

   You can double check the list of available `rake tasks` by executing the command

   ```
   rake -T
   ```

---

**NOTE:**

Just for your reference, check out this awesome Railscasts by Ryan Bates: [New Gem with Bundler](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler)